# Is there a way to run Bash scripts on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash

I have bought and I use Windows 7 Ultimate, and I like to use it to develop applications. One of the down sides (as with every OS) is that I can not run Bash scripts. Is there a way to run Bash scripts on Windows by installing some software? It is ok if it does not work 100%, but as long as the most common functionality is available it should be great.

Comment: http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/

Comment: [run bash on windows10](https://superuser.com/a/1217889/623314)

Comment: You can use [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/en/BashOnWindows.html) or [cmder](http://cmder.net/)

Comment: @stormy - these are console emulators and do not provide a shell. These can be used to run CMD, PowerShell or even a bash shell, if you have one installed.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), which includes Bash among many other GNU and Unix utilities (without whom its unlikely that bash will be very useful anyway).

Another option is [MinGW's MSYS](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw) which includes bash and a smaller set of the more important utilities such as awk (you may also want to check the competing fork - [Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php)). Personally I would have preferred Cygwin because it includes such heavy lifting tools as Perl and Python which I find I cannot live without, while MSYS skimps on these and assumes you are going to install them yourself.

**Updated**:
If anyone is interested in this answer and is running MS-Windows 10, please note that MS-Windows 10 has a "[Windows Subsystem For Linux](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/)" feature which - once enabled - allows you to install a user-mode image of Ubuntu and then run Bash on that. This provides 100% compatibility with Ubuntu for debugging and running Bash scripts, but this setup is completely standalone from Windows and you cannot use Bash scripts to interact with Windows features (such as processes and APIs) except for limited access to files through the [DrvFS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/) feature.

Comment: See [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) for more info.

Comment: WSL got deprecated for Windows 10 S now... :(

Comment: Not deprecated, it's just one of the features that you don't get if you buy the cheaper Windows "*S*mall edition". It's also not available in the Home Edition, IIRC.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan - The Git port to Windows, as well as a few other "command-line oriented" applications (Github Desktop as a notable example) also come with a Windows port of Bash. These, more often then not, are MinGW ports (i.e. compiled using MinGW and MSYS for Posix compatibility). Specifically, if you look at your Git for Windows installation, you'd see the `mingw32` directory that contains basically MSYS. So Git for Windows is MinGW that includes Git (its optional in the MSYS installer) with a "nicer" installer: https://superuser.com/a/1362301/10942

Comment: Also:  https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Relationship-to-Git-for-Windows

Comment: The mingw website in the answer is old. [This is the new one](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php)

Comment: @Jdeep the website is indeed old, but the correct one is https://osdn.net/projects/mingw . The Mingw-w64 project you link to is a fork that is older than this answer and I should have known about it and mentioned it. Thanks for letting me know, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 73):

Best Option I could find is [Git Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) Just install it and then right click on and click "Git Bash Here" this will open a bash window[image]

This will open a bash window like this: [image]

and the linux commands work...

I've tried 'sh' , 'vi' , 'ssh' , 'curl' ,etc... commands

Comment: You may as well just install MinGW without the extra bloat of Git if all you want is its shell.

Comment: I already had github desktop installed (and thus git), but I hid the context menu items, so I just clicked the windows Start button and typed Bash and pressed enter to open "Git Bash" (which is really MinGW).

Answer (score 31):

If you're looking for something a little more native, you can use [getGnuWin32](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) to install all of the Unix command line tools that have been ported. That plus [winBash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) gives you *most* of a working Unix environment. Add [console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) for a better terminal emulator and you almost can't tell you're on Windows!

Cygwin is a better toolkit overall, but I have found myself running into surprise problems because of the divide between it and Windows. None of these solutions are as good as a native Linux system though.

You may want to look into using [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) to create a linux VM with your distro of choice. Set it up to share a folder with the host os, and you can use a true linux development environment, and share with windows. Just watch out for those EOL markers, they get ya every time.

Comment: Or CoLinux : http://www.colinux.org/

Comment: colinux doesn't work on 64-bit (yet)

Comment: Does anyone know of a successor to the win-bash project? It is no longer actively developed and stuck on bash v 1.14 (bash proper, as of this post, is v 4.4)

Comment: @Bjartr The Microsoft folks have added a feature to allow a [native version of bash to run on windows 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/04/06/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-download-now-3/)

Comment: @SpencerRathbun 
That will only run on Windows 10, I happen to be on Windows 7. I'm also not sure how it plays with mixing linux and windows executables and paths so it may not be any better (from my perspective) than cygwin bash.

Comment: @hexicle There's something on going for the 64bit, but not quite ready though [colinux64](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/colinux/code/branches/devel-64bit/README64)

Answer (score 19):

Best option? Windows 10. Native Bash support!

Comment: No, not best options.
You just run linux that way, not bash IN windows - you cannot launch Windows executables from that bash (unless you workaround it with `cbwin`...but that's already too much fuss for just a workaround).

Comment: 'Best' option is probably a matter of taste. So maybe you're right. However, it does enable me to run any (well .. most) bash scripts on my windows PC.

Comment: You can run virtual all bash scripts - as long as they do not try to interact with the host OS (Windows). WSL bash is a *lightweight virtualization* subsystem that can execute the *original* ELF binaries (ie Ubuntu) - but you cannot escape it!

Answer (score 13):

You can always install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to run a Unix shell under Windows. I used Cygwin extensively with Window XP.

Comment: What package do I need to install to run UNIX Shell in Cygwin?

Comment: @rFactor the Cygwin page includes a windows installer with all of the necessary components.

Comment: The Cygwin site explains what has been ported and how to install it. If all you want is a shell then the basic Cygwin install should be enough.

Answer (score 11):

After installing git-extentions (http://gitextensions.github.io/) you can run .sh file from the command prompt. (No ./script.sh required, just run it like a bat/cmd file)
Or you can run them in a "full" bash environment by using the MinGW  Git bash shell.

I am not a great fan of Cygwin (yes I am sure it's really powerful), so running bash scripts on windows without having to install it perfect for me.

Comment: I do not know what is git-extensions but its description says it is a graphical user interface for git. How would you run shell scripts from this tool? Perhaps you mean to run them with msys bash that it includes?

Comment: Just to confirm - git-extensions does include a copy of bash and it sets it in the path. I tried `bash` from a powershell instance, failed, installed git-extensions and retried and it worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

In order to run natively, you will likely need to use Cygwin (which I cannot live without when using Windows).  So right off the bat, +1 for Cygwin.  Anything else would be uncivilized.

HOWEVER, that being said, I have recently begun using a combination of utilities to easily PORT Bash scripts to Windows so that my anti-Linux coworkers can easily run complex tasks that are better handled by GNU utilities.

I can usually port a Bash script to Batch in a very short time by opening the original script in one pane and writing a Batch file in the other pane.  The tools that I use are as follows:

- UnxUtils (http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/)
- Bat2Exe (http://bat2exe.net/)

I prefer UnxUtils to GnuWin32 because of the fact that [someone please correct me if I'm wrong] GnuWin utils normally have to be installed, whereas UnxUtils are standalone binaries that just work out-of-the-box.

However, the CoreUtils do not include some familiar *NIX utilities such as cURL, which is also available for Windows (curl.haxx.se/download.html).

I create a folder for the projects, and always SET PATH=. in the .bat file so that no other commands other than the basic CMD shell commands are referenced (as well as the particular UnxUtils required in the project folder for the Batch script to function as expected).

Then I copy the needed CoreUtils .exe files into the project folder and reference them in the .bat file such as ".\curl.exe -s google.com", etc.

The Bat2Exe program is where the magic happens.  Once your Batch file is complete and has been tested successfully, launch Bat2Exe.exe, and specify the path to the project folder.  Bat2Exe will then create a Windows binary containing all of the files in that specific folder, and will use the first .bat that it comes across to use as the main executable.  You can even include a .ico file to use as the icon for the final .exe file that is generated.

I have tried a few of these type of programs, and many of the generated binaries get flagged as malware, but the Bat2Exe version that I referenced works perfectly and the generated .exe files scan completely clean.

The resulting executable can be run interactively by double-clicking, or run from the command line with parameters, etc., just like a regular Batch file, except you will be able to utilize the functionality of many of the tools that you will normally use in Bash.

I realize this is getting quite long, but if I may digress a bit, I have also written a Batch script that I call PortaBashy that my coworkers can launch from a network share that contains a portable Cygwin installation.  It then sets the %PATH% variable to the normal *NIX format (/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin), etc. and can either launch into the Bash shell itself or launch the more-powerful and pretty MinTTY terminal emulator.

There are always numerous ways to accomplish what you are trying to set out to do; it's just a matter of combining the right tools for the job, and many times it boils down to personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

There's one more theoretical possibility to do it: professional versions of Windows have built-in POSIX support, so bash could have been compiled for Windows natively.

Pity, but I still haven't found a compiled one myself...

Comment: POSIX sybsystem on Windows has been abandoned [1]. Being replaced by the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" which is based on the "Drawbridge" lightweight virtualization system to run unmodified Ubuntu-bash.  
But there are some nuances, e.g. once inside this system, you cannot call Windows executables anymore!

[1] https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/

Comment: @ankostis, Actually, with CU you can...