# Installing Context broker GE in Fiware

Tags: token, fiware-orion, fiware

I try to install the `Orion Context Broker`, I first registered an account in
Fiware Lab, but the user guide says that I need to get and run the
`token_script.sh` in order to get a token, I have no idea what this means.

Comment: You can start here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805295/whats-a-sh-file

Answer (score 2):

In FIWARE Lab you can either deploy an instance of CentOS with Orion Context Broker already installed, or a fresh one on which to install it yourself. Which way are you doing it?

You only need a token if you want to connect to a public instance of Orion, such as the one in Santander (see [this](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#FI-LAB_context_management_platform) for more info on that).

The way it works is that you get a token (you need a FIWARE account, which you already have) using that script, and then use it in succesive calls to the Orion API.

Bottom line: if you just want to check out Orion Context Broker you don't need any tokens. Just set up your Orion VM in the cloud (Cloud tab in FIWARE Lab, orion-psb-R4.1 image). If you want to access Orion Context Broker deployed in a publicly accesible instance (such as the one in Santander) then you would need a token.

Comment: Is it necessary, then, to create a Virtual Machine in Fi-Labs with CentOS??

Comment: Three options: 1) Deploy image with Orion installed already (CentOS); 2) Deploy a CentOS image and install Orion yourself; 3) Download (rpm) or check out the code (git) and install anywhere else.

CentOS is the officially supported one, but it will work like a charm in Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: There are 4 instances of CentOS in FI-Lab. How I can know what have installed already?

Comment: `cat /etc/redhat-release` will give you the CentOS version. Keep in mind that the one with Orion preinstalled is called `orion-psb-image-R4.1`