# How to Run Unix command in Matlab in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, matlab, unix, command

In this MATLAB code, command is identified for UNIX platforms. However, I am using Win7. How can I run that command in Matlab in Windows?

```
command = ['Code/ExternalCode/kmeans/./kmeans_clustering.sh -i ' 'TemporaryResults/Features_ForKmeans' ' -p 2 -d -n ' num2str(k)];
system(command);
labels_kmeans = dlmread('TemporaryResults/Features_ForKmeans.membership');
labels_kmeans(:,1) = [];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options, both assume the commands which are executed within the script are runnable on Windows, i.e. the programs that are executed exist and are compiled for Windows.

**1.) Try to run the unmodified shell/bash script on Windows:**

You need to install an interpreter which can run your script on windows, have a look at this SO question: [Is there a way to run Bash scripts on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413377/is-there-a-way-to-run-bash-scripts-on-windows)

**2.) Re-write the script to [Windows batch format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file)**

This depends on the actual script you are running and involves finding the batch equivalent commands which correspond to the ones contained in your .sh script.

Comment: Cygwin is a good tool to run Unix command. However, I don't know how to manage that tool from Matlab.

Comment: @michaelscolfield there should be a bash.exe in you cywgin installation which will execute the script, so something like `system('c:\path\to\cygwin\bin\bash.exe kmeans_clustering.sh -i TemporaryResults/Features_ForKmeans ... ')` should work