# execute bash script from shared folder in windows explorer

Tags: linux, windows, bash, execute

I have a network with windows and Ubuntu linux machines on it.  The linux machine has a shared folder that allows the windows machines to see the files in this folder.  I would like to allow windows users to execute a bash script that is in the shared folder.
1. Is this possible?
2. If so, how do I make it happen?

Comment: Execute on the Linux or Windows machine?

Comment: I want it to execute on the Linux machine, not on a Windows machine.  I would just like to trigger the execution from a windows machine.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot execute the scripts via your shared folders for security reasons. If you are using file sharing services such as NFS or Samba you probably aren't allowed to do that.

The simplest way to execute bash scripts remotely from Windows is using a shortcut to [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) with the location of your script on the Windows machine and login credentials to the Linux box.

**Storing your password in plain text is not considered safe,** as anyone who has physical access to the computer can retrieve your password trivially. Only do this if you know what you're doing. Omitting `-pw yourPassword` will require you to enter your password each time you run the script.

The target of your shortcut will look something similar to this:

```
C:\putty.exe user@192.168.0.200 -pw yourPassword -m "C:\path\to\test.bash"
```

[image: PuTTY Shortcut]

Where test.bash is your bash script. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

touch itWorked
```

Result:

```
[root@pivos-m3 ~]# ll itWorked
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           0 Sep 23 14:05 itWorked*
```

Alternatively, you could probably write a Batch file script to execute the bash script over ssh, but PuTTY is a much simpler approach.

Comment: But my bash script is not on my windows machine.  It is on my linux machine.

Comment: You can write a short script to call that script. `/bin/bash /path/to/script.`

Comment: I like this idea, but I'm getting an error when I try this of "unable to open command file "/bin/bash"  My command line looks like this...                           "C:\putty.exe" user@192.168.150.150 -pw blahblah -m /bin/bash /path/to/script

Comment: If i remove everything from -m and afterwards, and run it I get logged into the linux machine as I would hope.  So I am able to reach the machine and have the first part of the command line correct.

Comment: I finally got it to work.  Not exactly what I expected, but it does the job.  I had to copy the script from the linux machine and put it on my Windows machine.  Then above solution works.  Since I could not control where the script was running on the linux machine, I had to perform a 'cd' command to make sure i was in the direcory I wanted.  I also had to add a -t to the end of the command line to re-enable tty, since the -m command does not enable it by default.

Comment: Here is my final solution...  "C:\putty.exe" user@192.168.150.150 -pw blahblah -m "C:\path\2\script" -t

Comment: Awesome! Note: It's good practice to write your bash scripts so that they can be executed from any directory. You can reference the script location using `MY_DIR=$(dirname $0)` and prefixing `"$MY_DIR/"` to all of your local calls.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. Windows *doesn't* have Bash. It has Batch, which is a relic of the pre-NT shell script for DOS.

However, you may want to have a poke around this question: [Is there a way to run Bash scripts on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413377/is-there-a-way-to-run-bash-scripts-on-windows), as it contains the answer to your Question 2.