# Compile QT source codes from within code

Tags: c++, bash, qt, qt5

I'm using dynamically compiled and loaded libraries. My go to solution for making this easier on me was just to create a bash code that I call to compile everything, but I'm currently working on porting this to Windows and I'm not sure how to achieve the same result.

Also, it's a QT application, so usage of qmake instead of g++ is required.

Code I'm executing: (I always supply this with an argument of the file name)

```
#! /bin/bash

cd "${0%/*}";
if [ $# = 0  ]; then echo "Error: No Arguments Supplied"; exit 7; fi;
if ! [ -a "$1.cc" ]; then echo "Error: Invalid Arguments Supplied"; exit 7; fi;

rm -f "$1.so";

cp template.pro tmp.pro;
echo "QT += widgets" >> tmp.pro;
echo "SOURCES += $1.cc" >> tmp.pro;
echo "CONFIG += c++11" >> tmp.pro;

qmake -norecursive tmp.pro;
make;
mv libtmp.so.1.0.0 "$1.so";

rm -f Makefile tmp.pro *.o;
find . -name 'libtmp.so*' -delete;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to install bash on Windows machine. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413377/is-there-a-way-to-run-bash-scripts-on-windows) or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/120045/how-to-execute-sh-file-on-windows) for example (I believe there are many other sources where you can read about executing bash script on Windows)

Second, unfortunately your `template.pro` and `tmp.pro` files will not be compatible between Linux (or Unix) and Windows. Most obvious example from your code is `libtmp.so` - on Windows libraries will have different names and extension `.dll`, but there will be other differences as well.

You'll need to use conditions in your `.pro` files:

```
#
# Windows section:
#
win32 {
# pro text for Windows here
}

#
# Linux/Unix section
#
unix {
# pro text for Linux/Unix here
}

# possible common part here
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on .pro file.
I would rather not have to install anything new on the machines, I'm trying to make this portable - It's a school project and they told us kinda late that It has to be run on windows.

Comment: I am not sure you can write a script that will be "ready to use" on all "naked" Windows and Linux machines (i.e. without additional software installed). At least I don't know about any scripting language supported by both systems "out of box". I am afraid you'll need to write your small software (probably using Qt) and build it for Linux and for Windows