# I am trying to run a script in powershell and it won't execute

Tags: powershell

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bcYU.png)

I am suppose to get the following when I run **$ target_new_environment**

Please select a connected device

1) 192.168.57.101:5555

2) C021UQ53170436

3) C010UC43010546

4) C021UQ50430029

Please select your desired target environment:

1) Prod-US

2) Prod-EU

3) Sandbox

4) Localhost

Please help.

Comment: `$target_new_environment` is a variable definition and not a script execution command. What's the name of the script you want to execute?

Comment: $target_new_environment

https://github.com/clover/clover-android-sdk/blob/master/scripts/target_new_environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell script files have file extension `.ps1`. The script you linked in the comment is a bash script and not a powershell script. So you have to execute that script with bash.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Install bash on windows and execute the script. For information about running bash scripts on windows see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413377/is-there-a-way-to-run-bash-scripts-on-windows)

Comment: I downloaded cygwin64 and tried and it says no such file or directory.

Comment: using git.bash target_new_environment

Comment: does the script `target_new_environment` exist in the current directory? You can check by using `dir` command