# Is there a Terminal like the one on OS X for Windows

Tags: php

I usually work on OS X for most of my web developments. But I just can't get into the Windows Terminal, it feels so clunky. Is there a terminal out there for Windows which looks and feels like the one on OS X?

I know that Linux has a simulair terminal which I like aswell. I want something like that on Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run Bash scripts on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413377/is-there-a-way-to-run-bash-scripts-on-windows)

Comment: You don't like the look of the window or you want *nix type commands or what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx) if you want minimal Linux like terminal and also [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) which has a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows..

Also next versions of windows is going to ship with TRUE Linux subsystem & bash shell

> ...and there was much rejoicing....

Comment: 'yayyyyyy, yayyy'

Comment: Thanks alot, going to check those out! :)