# Sort folders into alphabetic subfolders

Tags: vbscript

Good day, 
Please, help me with vbscript sorting folders into alphabetic folders. I mean, all folders with name starting with A go to folder A, with B - to B etc.

Comment: Take a look at [`FileSystemObject`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2004/10/20/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-files-in-a-folder-and-its-subfolders/)

Answer (score 0):

Install bash...[Learn Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413405/1417725)

Use a bash script... [Learn Here](http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/)

```
#!/bin/bash
    dirs=(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z)
    shopt -s nocasematch

    for file in *
    do
        for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
        do
            if [[ $file =~ ^[$dir] ]]
            then
                mv "$file" "$dir"
                break
            fi
        done
    done
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I cannot use bash script because I am using Windows 7.

Comment: I've edited my answer to point to instructions for getting setup to run bash from win7.