# I'm trying to run a .sh file on command prompt and I'm not familiar with the commands

Tags: command, prompt

> time ./wordcount.sh
>   The system cannot accept the time entered.
>   Enter the new time:

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run Bash scripts on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413377/is-there-a-way-to-run-bash-scripts-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using dos as the tag suggests, then `time` is the utility to change the system time. You are passing the string `./wordcount.sh` as a parameter to `time` and the program is complaining because it cannot interpret `./wordcount.sh` as a valid time.

Try running `time /?` to see a list of valid parameters that can be passed to the time utility

For more information on how to run bash scripts in windows see:
[Is there a way to run Bash scripts on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413377/is-there-a-way-to-run-bash-scripts-on-windows)

Comment: If that works for you, please can you vote up the answer and mark it as  the accepted answer? Thanks @dmitri2