# Run a bash script with C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, bash, powershell

I am trying to write a program in C++ that can execute a bash script on Windows and then read the output of the bash script and store it into a string or something like that. Is this even possible without installing any extra software on Windows? If so, how?

Also, would it work if I wrote the program on Linux with a Posix library and then cross-compiled the C++ program for Windows inside Linux and then move it over to Windows where it needs to execute the bash script?

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with PowerShell, so why did you add that tag?

Comment: @Theo
In case, some Windows command could execute a bash script.

Comment: I think your first step is to install bash or use WSL although if this is software that clients will be using you may want to rethink the bash requirement.

Comment: @drescherjm
But then you would also have to make the client install bash on his computer if he uses the software.

Comment: I thought about that. You may want to rethink this requirement and rewrite the script. I expect your question is what is the easiest path to convert a bash script to something usable on windows without the need to install bash because this will be on a client's machine.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413377/is-there-a-way-to-run-bash-scripts-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413377/is-there-a-way-to-run-bash-scripts-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the popen function.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = popen("bash script.sh", "r");
```

Now you can read the output just like you would read a file. Example:

```
char output[100];
fgets(output, sizeof(output), fp);
```

Comment: is it _popen on Windows?

Comment: I think its `_popen`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=vs-2019

Comment: When I execute the C++ program, it asks me how I want to open the the script. This is a problem since I am sure you cannot run a bash script with CMD or Powershell.

Comment: On windows, an alternative should be `batch scripting`. You can use git bash to run bash scripts on windows I guess.