# Openshift: list unused secrets

Tags: openshift-client-tools, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise

I have lots of secrets since last year and not sure which ones are in use by applications. Since I don't want to accidently delete in-use secret, I want to use oc.exe CLI and find all unused secrets.
Somewhere I found the below cmd however it throws me an error:

```
for s in $(oc get secret --no-headers | awk '{print $1}'); do  echo $s; (oc get all -o yaml; oc describe sa )|grep $s |wc -l; done
```

Error: s was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it on my openshift cluster it's working fine.

this command is meant to be run on bash , what do you mean by using oc.exe ?

( i would have commented , but i don't have enough reputation ).

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work on mine. By oc.exe I meant, I am using the Openshift CLI on my Windows cmd. Other general commands such as oc login, oc project are working fine.

Comment: this command is entended to be used in bash ( linux shell ) , it won't work in windows

Comment: So what would be the equivalent command for windows e.g. in PowerShell?

Comment: A workaround on Windows could be to use the Git Bash as detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413377/is-there-a-way-to-run-bash-scripts-on-windows