# Is possible to self-sign my app for testing?

Tags: windows, testing, self-signed

Is there any possibility to self-sign my app for testing? Windows everytime is warning me before execution of my app (I have to test client-server). So will be it very hard to do that?

Comment: Sure, just double-click your self-signed certificate and follow the prompts to add it to the trusted roots certificate store.  (IIRC, you do have to specifically select the trusted roots store, the "automatically select a store" option doesn't put it in the right place.)

Comment: But how to generate that certificate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355568/create-a-ssl-certificate-on-windows